# Count the occurance in each line from a txt file and save them into matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I am new to python and my first task is to save the data from a .txt file into a matrix.

.txt file that contains the following data:

```
0 1 1 

0

2 3 2 4
```

I want to read the .txt file and transform it into a 2D matrix in python by counting the occurrence of each number in each line and save it to a matrix where each line is considered as a frame.

The output would be come

```
          c0 c1 c2 c3 c4

frame0    1     2    0    0    0

frame1    1     0    0    0    0  

frame2    0     0    2    1    1
```

For instance, the number 0 occurs once in the first line where number 1 occurs twice.

Comment: you need your first task to be done by someone? Please try something your own and if you get any error post here.

Comment: @Mufeed Sorry for the inconvenience, I will do it the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of each item in a list and map the items to their counts in a dict:

```
from collections import Counter
text='''0 1 1
0
2 3 2 4'''
matrix = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    counts = Counter(line.split())
    matrix.append([counts.get(str(i), 0) for i in range(max(map(int, counts.keys())) + 1)])
frame_size = max(map(len, matrix))
matrix = [frame + [0] * (frame_size - len(frame)) for frame in matrix]
print(matrix)
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was so helpful.